# SQLIte Database is not being created in Kotlin app

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I creating a database application on AndroidStudio using Kotlin for a University project. I am trying to create the database using SQLite. Below is my DBHelper kt file that I created to start the database. When I call one of the functions to create the database, the application crashes. When I check the .db files from the database in SQL Cypher the tables do not appear. The errors aren't descriptive enough for me to find out how to fix it. Thank you for your help.

```
package com.example.guviolinapp

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper

class DBHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1) {

    companion object{
        //Companion object that holds the name of everything in the database
        private val DATABASE_NAME = "violininfo.db"
        private val GAME_TABLE = "game_table"
        private val COL_GAME_NUMBER = "game_number"
        private val COL_GAME_SCORE = "game_score"
        private val SCORE_TABLE = "score_table"
        private val COL_SCORE_LEVEL = "quiz_level"
        private val COL_QUIZ_SCORE = "quiz_score"
        private val QUESTION_TABLE = "questions_table"
        private val COL_QUIZ_LEVEL = "quiz_level"
        private val COL_QUESTION_NUM = "question_number"
        private val COL_QUIZ_QUESTION = "quiz_questions"
        private val COL_IMAGE_PATH = "quiz_image_path"
        private val COL_QUIZ_OPTION_ONE = "quiz_options_one"
        private val COL_QUIZ_OPTION_TWO = "quiz_options_two"
        private val COL_QUIZ_OPTION_THREE = "quiz_options_three"
        private val COL_QUIZ_OPTION_FOUR = "quiz_options_four"
        private val COL_QUIZ_ANSWER = "quiz_answer"
    }

    //On create of the Application creating the actual database in the device
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        //Variable that holds the SQL query to create the table
        val CREATE_GAME_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $GAME_TABLE" +
                "($COL_GAME_NUMBER INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "$COL_GAME_SCORE INTEGER" +
                ")"
        //Variable that holds the SQL query to create the table
        val CREATE_QUESTION_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE $QUESTION_TABLE" +
                "($COL_QUIZ_LEVEL INTEGER, " +
                "$COL_QUESTION_NUM INTEGER, " +
                "$COL_QUIZ_QUESTION TEXT, " +
                "$COL_IMAGE_PATH TEXT, " +
                "$COL_QUIZ_OPTION_ONE TEXT, " +
                "$COL_QUIZ_OPTION_TWO TEXT , " +
                "$COL_QUIZ_OPTION_THREE TEXT, " +
                "$COL_QUIZ_OPTION_FOUR TEXT, " +
                "$COL_QUIZ_ANSWER INTEGER" +
                "PRIMARY KEY ($COL_QUIZ_LEVEL, $COL_QUESTION_NUM)" +
                ")"
        //Variable that holds the SQL query to create the table
        val CREATE_SCORE_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE $SCORE_TABLE" +
                "($COL_SCORE_LEVEL INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "$COL_QUIZ_SCORE INTEGER" +
                "FOREIGN KEY $COL_SCORE_LEVEL REFERENCES $QUESTION_TABLE($COL_QUIZ_LEVEL) ON DELETE CASCADE" +
                ")"

        //Functions that execute the sql script. The first one prevents null in the db
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE $QUESTION_TABLE($COL_QUIZ_LEVEL INTEGER, $COL_QUESTION_NUM INTEGER, $COL_QUIZ_QUESTION TEXT, $COL_IMAGE_PATH TEXT, $COL_QUIZ_OPTION_ONE TEXT, $COL_QUIZ_OPTION_TWO TEXT , $COL_QUIZ_OPTION_THREE TEXT, $COL_QUIZ_OPTION_FOUR TEXT, $COL_QUIZ_ANSWER INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY ($COL_QUIZ_LEVEL, $COL_QUESTION_NUM))")
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE $GAME_TABLE($COL_GAME_NUMBER INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $COL_GAME_SCORE INTEGER)")
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE $SCORE_TABLE($COL_SCORE_LEVEL INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $COL_QUIZ_SCORE INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY ($COL_SCORE_LEVEL) REFERENCES $QUESTION_TABLE($COL_QUIZ_LEVEL) ON DELETE CASCADE)")
        fillQuestionsTable()
    }

    //Function that drops the database and remakes it for when the database is updated. It can be done two ways.
    //The app can be deleted, or the version can be increased
    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        val DROP_SCORE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $SCORE_TABLE"
        val DROP_GAME_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $GAME_TABLE"
        val DROP_QUESTION_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $QUESTION_TABLE"

        db.execSQL(DROP_SCORE_TABLE)
        db.execSQL(DROP_GAME_TABLE)
        db.execSQL(DROP_QUESTION_TABLE)
        onCreate(db)
    }

    override fun onConfigure(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        super.onConfigure(db)
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true)
    }


    //Function to insert values into the Score table
    fun insertScoreTable(quizLevel: Int, quizScore: Int): Boolean? {
        //Creates the writable database that can be accessed
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        //Function to insert values that will be inserted into the database
        val cv = ContentValues()
        //Inserting the values with a specific identifier in which the value needs to be inserted
        cv.put(COL_SCORE_LEVEL, quizLevel)
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_SCORE, quizScore)
        //Executing the actual insert database
        val res = db.insert(SCORE_TABLE, null, cv)
        return !res.equals(-1)
    }

    //Function to insert values into the Game table
    fun insertGameTable(gameNum: Int, gameScore: Int): Boolean? {
        //Creates the writable database that can be accessed
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        //Function to insert values that will be inserted into the database
        val cv = ContentValues()
        //Inserting the values with a specific identifier in which the value needs to be inserted
        cv.put(COL_GAME_NUMBER, gameNum)
        cv.put(COL_GAME_SCORE, gameScore)
        //Executing the actual insert database
        val res = db.insert(GAME_TABLE, null, cv)
        return !res.equals(-1)
    }

    //Function to insert values into the Questions table
    private fun insertQuestionsTable(questionTable: QuestionsTable) {
        //Creates the writable database that can be accessed
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        //Function to insert values that will be inserted into the database
        val cv = ContentValues()
        //Inserting the values with a specific identifier in which the value needs to be inserted
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_LEVEL, questionTable.quiz_level)
        cv.put(COL_QUESTION_NUM, questionTable.question_number)
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_QUESTION, questionTable.quiz_questions)
        cv.put(COL_IMAGE_PATH, questionTable.quiz_image_path)
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_ONE, questionTable.quiz_option_one)
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_TWO, questionTable.quiz_option_two)
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_THREE, questionTable.quiz_option_three)
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_FOUR, questionTable.quiz_option_four)
        cv.put(COL_QUIZ_ANSWER, questionTable.quiz_answer)
        //Executing the actual insert database
        val res = db.insert(QUESTION_TABLE, null, cv)
        //return !res.equals(-1)
    }

    //Function to insert all the questions into the database
    private fun fillQuestionsTable() {
        //Variable with the data class holding the values for each question
        val l1q1 = QuestionsTable(1, 1, "What note is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l1q1", "Minim",
            "Semibreve", "Crochet", "Quaver", 4)
        //Calling the insertQuestionsTable to insert the question
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q1)

        val l1q2 = QuestionsTable(1, 2, "What note is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l1q2", "Quaver",
            "Minim", "Crochet", "Semibreve", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q2)

        val l1q3 = QuestionsTable(1, 3, "What rest is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l1q3", "Whole",
            "Eighth", "Half", "Quarter", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q3)

        val l1q4 = QuestionsTable(1, 4, "What rest is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l1q4", "Quarter",
            "Eighth", "Whole", "Half", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q4)

        val l1q5 = QuestionsTable(1, 5, "What rest is this?",
        "@drawable/questionImage/l1q5", "Whole",
        "Eighth", "Quarter", "Half", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q5)

        val l1q6 = QuestionsTable(1, 6, "What rest is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l1q6", "Quarter",
            "Eighth", "Whole", "Half", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q6)

        val l1q7 = QuestionsTable(1, 7, "What note is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l1q7", "Minim",
            "Quaver", "Semibreve", "Crochet", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q7)

        val l1q8 = QuestionsTable(1, 8, "What note is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l1q8", "Quaver",
            "Semibreve", "Crochet", "Minim", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q8)

        val l1q9 = QuestionsTable(1, 9, "How many beats in this rest?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l1q9", "Half Beat",
            "One Beat", "Two Beats", "Four Beats", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q9)

        val l1q10 = QuestionsTable(1, 10, "How many beats in this rest?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l1q10", "Four Beats",
            "One Beat", "Two Beats", "Half Beat", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q10)

        val l1q11 = QuestionsTable(1, 11, "How many beats in this rest?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l1q11", "One Beat",
            "Half Beat", "Two Beats", "Four Beats", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q11)

        val l1q12 = QuestionsTable(1, 12, "How many beats in this note?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l1q12", "Four Beats",
            "One Beat", "Half Beat", "Two Beats", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q12)

        val l1q13 = QuestionsTable(1, 13, "How many beats in this rest?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l1q13", "Two Beats",
            "One Beat", "Four Beats", "Half Beat", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q13)

        val l1q14 = QuestionsTable(1, 14, "How many beats in this note?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l1q14", "Two Beats",
            "Half Beat", "Four Beats", "One Beat", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q14)

        val l1q15 = QuestionsTable(1, 15, "How many beats in this note?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l1q15", "One Beat",
            "Four Beats", "Half Beat", "Two Beats", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l1q15)

        val l2q1 = QuestionsTable(2, 1, "What string is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l2q1", "D",
            "A", "G", "E", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q1)

        val l2q2 = QuestionsTable(2, 2, "What note is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l2q2", "F sharp",
            "E", "G sharp", "A", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q2)

        val l2q3 = QuestionsTable(2, 3, "What note is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l2q3", "G",
            "B", "A", "C", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q3)

        val l2q4 = QuestionsTable(2, 4, "What note is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l2q4", "E",
            "F sharp", "A", "G sharp", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q4)

        val l2q5 = QuestionsTable(2, 5, "What note is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l2q5", "G",
            "A", "B", "C", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q5)

        val l2q6 = QuestionsTable(2, 6, "What string is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l2q6", "A",
            "D", "E", "G", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q6)

        val l2q7 = QuestionsTable(2, 7, "What note is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l2q7", "B",
            "A", "C", "G", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q7)

        val l2q8 = QuestionsTable(2, 8, "What note is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l2q8", "E",
            "D", "G", "F sharp", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q8)

        val l2q9 = QuestionsTable(2, 9, "What note is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l2q9", "A",
            "B", "C sharp", "D", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q9)

        val l2q10 = QuestionsTable(2, 10, "What note is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l2q10", "F sharp",
            "D", "E", "G", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q10)

        val l2q11 = QuestionsTable(2, 11, "What note is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l2q11", "A",
            "B", "C sharp", "D", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q11)

        val l2q12 = QuestionsTable(2, 12, "What string is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l2q12", "D",
            "G", "E", "A", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q12)

        val l2q13 = QuestionsTable(2, 13, "What note is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l2q13", "C sharp",
            "D", "B", "A", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q13)

        val l2q14 = QuestionsTable(2, 14, "What note is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l2q14", "E",
            "G", "F sharp", "D", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q14)

        val l2q15 = QuestionsTable(2, 15, "What string is this?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l2q15", "A",
            "D", "G", "E", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l2q15)

        val l3q1 = QuestionsTable(3, 1, "What is this called?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l3q1", "Treble Clef",
            "Tie", "Stave", "Flat", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q1)

        val l3q2 = QuestionsTable(3, 2, "What is this called?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l3q2", "Stave",
            "Bass Clef", "Sharp", "Treble Clef", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q2)

        val l3q3 = QuestionsTable(3, 3, "What is this called?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l3q3", "Bar",
            "Stave", "Sharp", "Bass Clef", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q3)

        val l3q4 = QuestionsTable(3, 4, "What is this called?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l3q4", "Time Signature",
            "Treble Clef", "Natural", "Bass Clef", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q4)

        val l3q5 = QuestionsTable(3, 5, "What is this called?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l3q5", "Bar",
            "Key Signature", "Sharp", "Tie", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q5)

        val l3q6 = QuestionsTable(3, 6, "What is this called?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l3q6", "Treble Clef",
            "Key Signature", "Bar", "Tie", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q6)

        val l3q7 = QuestionsTable(3, 7, "What is this called?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l3q7", "Flat",
            "Sharp", "Bar", "Natural", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q7)

        val l3q8 = QuestionsTable(3, 8, "What is this called?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l3q8", "Treble Clef",
            "Flat", "Sharp", "Bass Clef", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q8)

        val l3q9 = QuestionsTable(3, 9, "What is this called?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l3q9", "Sharp",
            "Time Signature", "Flat", "Tie", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q9)

        val l3q10 = QuestionsTable(3, 10, "What is this called?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l3q10", "Bass Clef",
            "Bar", "Natural", "Sharp", 3)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q10)

        val l3q11 = QuestionsTable(3, 11, "What is this called?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l3q11", "Decrescendo",
            "Accent", "Forte", "Crescendo", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q11)

        val l3q12 = QuestionsTable(3, 12, "What is this called?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l3q12", "Decrescendo",
            "Forte", "Accent", "Piano", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q12)

        val l3q13 = QuestionsTable(3, 13, "What is this called?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l3q13", "Forte",
            "Accent", "Crescendo", "Decrescendo", 1)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q13)

        val l3q14 = QuestionsTable(3, 14, "What is this called?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l3q14", "Decrescendo",
            "Accent", "Crescendo", "Forte", 2)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q14)

        val l3q15 = QuestionsTable(3, 15, "What is this called?",
            "@drawable/questionImage/l3q15", "Forte",
            "Piano", "Accent", "Crescendo", 4)
        insertQuestionsTable(l3q15)


    }

    //Function get the questions back from the database.
    fun getAllQuestions(): ArrayList<QuestionsTable> {
        //Creating the ArrayList that holds the questions retrieved from the database
        val rv = ArrayList<QuestionsTable>()
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        //Query that gets the values from the database
        val csr = db.query(QUESTION_TABLE,null /* ALL columns */,null,null,null,null,null)

        //While loop that insert the values into the array list while there is a next value
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            //Adding values to the array list
            rv.add(
                //Inserting the values into the data class
                QuestionsTable(
                    //Getting the actual values from the query
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_LEVEL)),
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUESTION_NUM)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_QUESTION)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_IMAGE_PATH)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_ONE)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_TWO)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_THREE)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_OPTION_FOUR)),
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_ANSWER))
                )
            )

        }

        //Closing the database query
        csr.close()
        //Returning the ArrayList
        return rv
    }

    //Function get the scores back from the database.
    fun getAllScores(): ArrayList<ScoreTable> {
        //Creating the ArrayList that holds the questions retrieved from the database
        val rv = ArrayList<ScoreTable>()
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        //While loop that insert the values into the array list while there is a next value
        val csr = db.query(SCORE_TABLE,null /* ALL columns */,null,null,null,null,null)

        //While loop that insert the values into the array list while there is a next value
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            //Adding values to the array list
            rv.add(
                //Inserting the values into the data class
                ScoreTable(
                    //Getting the actual values from the query
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_SCORE_LEVEL)),
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_QUIZ_SCORE))
                )
            )
        }

        //Closing the database query
        csr.close()
        //Returning the ArrayList
        return rv
    }

    //Function get the Game scores back from the database.
    fun getAllGameScores(): ArrayList<GameTable> {
        //Creating the ArrayList that holds the questions retrieved from the database
        val rv = ArrayList<GameTable>()
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        //While loop that insert the values into the array list while there is a next value
        val csr = db.query(GAME_TABLE,null /* ALL columns */,null,null,null,null,null)

        //While loop that insert the values into the array list while there is a next value
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            //Adding values to the array list
            rv.add(
                //Inserting the values into the data class
                GameTable(
                    //Getting the actual values from the query
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_GAME_NUMBER)),
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_GAME_SCORE))
                )
            )
        }

        //Closing the database query
        csr.close()
        //Returning the ArrayList
        return rv
    }
}
```

This is the activity where I try and print out the entire ArrayList of all the values to see if anything is in the database.

```
package com.example.guviolinapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView

class QuizQuestionsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //Initialization of variables that will be used
    lateinit var myDb: DBHelper
    private var mQuizLevel: String? = null

    //Setting the database variable and it's context
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_questions)

        //Receiving the extra information from the Intent
        mQuizLevel = intent.getStringExtra("LevelInformation")

        myDb = DBHelper(this)

        val questionList = myDb.getAllQuestions()

        val tvOptionOne = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvOptionOne)

        Log.d("Database Query",questionList.toString())
    }
}
```

This is the Error I get when I start the activity.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.guviolinapp, PID: 9893
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.guviolinapp/com.example.guviolinapp.QuizQuestionsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:203)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
        at com.example.guviolinapp.DBHelper.insertQuestionsTable(DBHelper.kt:118)
        at com.example.guviolinapp.DBHelper.fillQuestionsTable(DBHelper.kt:143)
        at com.example.guviolinapp.DBHelper.onCreate(DBHelper.kt:65)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
        at com.example.guviolinapp.DBHelper.getAllQuestions(DBHelper.kt:372)
        at com.example.guviolinapp.QuizQuestionsActivity.onCreate(QuizQuestionsActivity.kt:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `fillQuestionsTable()` in your database helper `onCreate()` and that fill function eventually accesses `writableDatabase` which is the reason for the "called recursively" error.

Pass the `SQLiteDatabase` parameter from `onCreate()` down to the fill/insert functions and remove the `writableDatabase` accesses.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did what you said. I removed the writableDatabase accesses. Instead I added this
`private lateinit var db: SQLiteDatabase`
And this 
`this.db = db`

Now instead of it throwing an error code, the database isn't being created anymore. Theres no .db file